# Selenium cannot find Chrome Binary Stacktrace in environment

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium for a scraper script and the script works fine usually but I tried to use it in an environment and now I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  at block 12, line 6
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.pyline 69, in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.pyline 92, in __init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyline 277, in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyline 370, in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyline 435, in execute(self, driver_command, params)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.pyline 247, in check_response(self, response)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary Stacktrace: #0 0x55848dc3dcd3 <unknown> #1 0x55848da45968 <unknown> #2 0x55848da681b4 <unknown> #3 0x55848da658fa <unknown> #4 0x55848daa094a <unknown> #5 0x55848da9aaa3 <unknown> #6 0x55848da703fa <unknown> #7 0x55848da71555 <unknown> #8 0x55848dc852bd <unknown> #9 0x55848dc89418 <unknown> #10 0x55848dc6f36e <unknown> #11 0x55848dc8a078 <unknown> #12 0x55848dc63bb0 <unknown> #13 0x55848dca6d58 <unknown> #14 0x55848dca6ed8 <unknown> #15 0x55848dcc0cfd <unknown> #16 0x7f9d45e38609 <unknown>
```

the code triggering the error:

```
<ipython-input-13-91e95837f433>:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

What could be the issue? it works fine without environment

Answer (score 0):

Specify The `executable_path` Parameter Value When Initialize like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

You can find more docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, the service object error has disappeared however I am still getting the binary stacktrace error.

Comment: can you add your `code` please ?

Comment: Hi, it is just this line that throw error: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())), It works fine on its own but does not work in environment, I am using datalore jetbrains environment

Comment: @Akzy Where is the executable path specified in this code?

Comment: @presentformyfriends - Second last line